# mysql - pythagoras comparisons for nearest of many (table) to one (record in a table)

Tags: mysql, sql

Debutant today with OSX install of mySQL. I have imported two csv files as follows.
I have done this in Excel: but it breaks Excel with 1.6 billion calcs, even with VBA.
I have 500,000 OSGB Eastings and Northings (table 1) and I have 3,335 Eastings and Northings (table2) to be compared to find the nearest one to each of the coordinates in table 1. So for every one of 500,000 I have 3,335 Pythagoras calcs.

I gather the mySQL pythagoras is:
SQRT( POW(MY_Y_AXIS - Y_AXIS, 2) + POW(MY_X_AXIS-X_AXIS, 2) ) which I found while searching for answers.

I also gather PostGres may be a better idea.
There is also a date comparison constraint that the existence of each must be within 7 years before and five years after (+59 to -84).

My first thought was to make it simple and do Full Join, joining every record in table2 to every record in table 1, but that's 1.6 billion records and I read while searching that 122 million is thought to be "a lot".

This leaves a calculation to be performed on every record of table 1 against every record of table 2. I will not be surprised if this takes a "while" to run. That's fine. Great of it doesn't.

I am hoping this is as simple as ONE SQL Query, if a complicated one.
There are NO related fields.
The relation between these two tables will be created by this distance calculation. Distances above (say) one kilometre to be ignored (with a parameter).

This being my first post (ever) regarding mySQL I am not sure whether it is helpful to upload the working example in Excel.

I am doing my best here to follow the guidelines and have spent ages searching both in here and on the wider internet (web). I see an interesting list of "similar questions"..except none similar enough :-)

My principal question is how to incorporate pythagoras into a suitable query, presumably a "Cross Join"?

Version 5.7 of mySql - just downloaded and installed. Sequel-Pro client also just installed, used to import the two csv files.

Wondering if this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/gis-data-formats.html may simplify matters, can't see if it accepts OSGB Eastings and Northings.

Example file in Excel, see the DATA tab/sheet, tables coloured in blue, results in red. Table 2 is shown across the page instead of down like in a database..... just figuring out how to upload...no, can't see how. File is here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/uqm44wk4mprkweq/SiteTest9907-HOMECORNER-S_E.xlsx?dl=0

Comment: I figure that it will be hard to someone help you here. Maybe if you add some practical information it would be better. A small data sample from your two tables with the desired result would help a lot. Besides that, my two cents here is that I wouldn't use a database for this kind of process at all. I would put those information in files and would read then in parts and dividing this heavy job into threads to make it faster joining the data at the end of each thread. Read the files in parts will make the process feasible regarding excessive use of memory. Running it in a pretty good machine..

Comment: Will certainly help a lot. I used this technique back when I was working with NLP alongside a CRF processing, we did this processing in batches and in a powerful machine (32 cores, 128gb mem) even with that power it took some hours to run. Oooh and billions of registries was just a fraction of what we processed. God speed.

Comment: Thanks, I've just taken delivery of 128gb ram (a 64 gig upgrade) so I will see what that does, if anything. I'll also create an example to upload in Excel; I just can't visualise how a database calc would look. I'll illustrate the tables and results in this example. I imagine a process that checks each of table two's 3,335 coordinates against row/record one of table 1's coordinates, selects the smallest subject to being within (say) one kilometre, store that and go round again with record two of table one.. until "end if" as it were.

Comment: What method are you suggesting I try? Example here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/uqm44wk4mprkweq/SiteTest9907-HOMECORNER-S_E.xlsx?dl=0 SEE the DATA tab/sheet.